# MySQL SSH Connection Setup

Tags: ssh, mysql, openssh, mysql-workbench

I want to connect to a MySQL db (running Ubuntu 14.04) with my Mac (running Mavericks). I will be connecting remote- home to work. How do I setup the ssh connection on MySQL workbench? Also, where do I find the values for the fields below? These are required for Workbench connection.

```
1. SSH Hostname
2. SSH Username
3. SSH Password
4. SSH Key File
5. MySQL Hostname
```

So far: 
I have created a separate user, aside from root and granted+flushed privileges. A port forwarding rule for port X (as listed in the my.cnf file) has been setup via my router.

Does a port forwarding rule for port 22 for ssh also need to be setup on the router? Are any steps missing?

Comment: Following the instructions on this page: http://juristr.com/blog/2010/11/howto-mysql-workbench-to-remote-ubuntu/

I get the error: WbAdmin.autoDetectLocalInstance error. The test connection does go through via WorkBench- when I try save the connection the above error is displayed

Answer (score 1):

You should really check this link http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html to set up an easy SHH-tunnel using Putty.

After setting up the tunnel you should have all the needed information to fill the required fields in MySQL Workbench and have it up and running in no time!